# Не удается посчитать длину массива

Tags: python

Начал делать задание, но не до конца понимаю как его доделать.

Суть в том, что дохожу до того, что вывожу элементы, которые превышают сумму массива, но посчитать его длину не удаётся. Считаю длину, так как нужно вывести процент элементов, которые превышают средне значение массива.

Код:

```
ia = list(map(int, input("Список: \n").split()))
ib = sum(ia)
ic = ib/len(ia)
print("Среднее значение: ", ic)
for i in range(len(ia)):
    if ia[i] > ic:
        id = ia[i]
        print(id/len(ia), end = " ")
    else: print("Таких чисел нет ;c")
```

Пробовал `len(id[i]) / len(ia)`, но выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Прошу объяснить, что нужно переделать или же в чём ошибка вообще, а не решение :D

Comment: И что за ошибка?

Comment: @Miron закрывается cmd :D

Comment: @РостиславВасин это не ошибка. Программа завершается и консоль закрывается.

Answer (score 2):

Вводим дополнительную переменную для счета и считаем элементы, которые больше среднего.

```
ia = list(map(int, input("Список: \n").split()))
ib = sum(ia)
ic = ib/len(ia)
greater_than_average = 0
print("Среднее значение: ", ic)
for i in ia:
    if i > ic:
        greater_than_average += 1
    else:
        print("Таких чисел нет.") # такое может быть только если все числа равны
print("Больше среднего: ", greater_than_average/len(ia))
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь